# Batch commit did not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I run the following code to purge old data. Exact code was running `as is`  as SQL Agent job step pointing to a user database.   Expecting to commit with a batch of 10,000 rows.  2 days ago it did not do that, after terminating the session (reason of termination is not related to this question) rolled back all the delete and not just the last batch.

Anybody can point me to a reason why?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rowCount INT;

SET @rowCount= 1;

WHILE @rowCount > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DELETE TOP (10000) 
    dbo.TableName
    WHERE RecordedAt<DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE() )
   SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

Comment: I don't suppose your code was running in an outer transaction which made your code a nested transaction and your actual commit was only decrementing @@TRANCOUNT and not actually committing anything?

Comment: Is/Was your process running in chained transaction (aka implicit transaction; aka autocommit=false) mode?  If so, your entire `while` loop would have been executed within a single transaction, with the net result that a) you would need to perform another `commit tran` once your batch completed or b) any issuance of a rollback tran (or connection termination) would cause the entire batch (ie, all of your DELETEs) to be rolled back.

Comment: Exact code was running as a step of SQL Agent job.  Nothing else is in that step.

Comment: I'd suggest putting in some 'poor-man-debugging' Raiserror print type statements indicating a Timestamp and rows affected after each delete and running it outside of a Sql Agent job - what happens then?  On the surface, I don't see anything jumping out as a problem with your approach, but we don't know too much about how the Sql Agent job is configured, what database it's pointing to, etc.

Comment: You might also check @@TRANCOUNT after your COMMIT to ensure that your transaction is indeed standing alone.

Comment: Agree with other commenters that it sounds like @@trancount was more than 1 (somehow). Perhaps you can re-run the job and look at the sessions's open_transaction_count in sys.dm_exec_requests to see if it is picking up an "extra" BEGIN TRAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difficult to diagnose definitively based on the information provided but the likely cause is the batch was inadvertently invoked with a transaction already open. I suggest one or more the following to prevent the problem going forward:

- Add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to the batch to help ensure explicit
  transactions are automatically rolled back.
- Remove the superfluous `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` since the automatic
  single-statement transaction will fully rollback a delete batch if an error
  occurs.
- Add error handling

Comment: You are saying the BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT is superfluous, is that so? Can you show any reference so I can read about this. The reason im asking is that we have this apparoch to make sure the log file doesnt fill the disk and we do take log backups while the purge is running.

Comment: Yes, the explicit `BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT` is redundant unless you've changed the default behavior with `SET IMPLICT_TRANSACTIONS ON`. The default behavior is autocommit so each statement is an atomic transaction. Explicit transactions needed for multi-statement transactions. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878.aspx.